# Beamer - \visible and \cellcolor

Tags: beamer

I'm creating a beamer presentation. I have this table:

```
\begin{array}
    \visible<1->{\cellcolor{Blue}{0}} & \visible<2->{\cellcolor{Red}{0 + 1}} \\
    \visible<1->{\cellcolor{Yellow}{0 + 1 + 2}} & \visible<2->{\cellcolor{Green}{0 + 1 + 2 + 3}}
\end{array}
```

Unfortunately, the cell colors are visible from the start, before there is text. Using `\only` solves the color issue, but destroys the text alignment.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Here's a compilable example:

```
\documentclass[table,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    $\begin{array}{ll}
        \visible<1->{\cellcolor{Blue}{0}} & \visible<2->{\cellcolor{Red}{0 + 1}} \\
        \visible<3->{\cellcolor{Yellow}{0 + 1 + 2}} & \visible<4->{\cellcolor{Green}{0 + 1 + 2 + 3}} \\
    \end{array}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please turn the example into a full compilable document, starting from `\documentclass` and packages loaded.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using `\pause` in each element of the table?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[table,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    $\begin{array}{ll}
        \visible<1->{\cellcolor{Blue}{0}}\pause & \visible<2->{\cellcolor{Red}{0 + 1}}\pause \\
        \visible<3->{\cellcolor{Yellow}{0 + 1 + 2}}\pause & \visible<4->{\cellcolor{Green}{0 + 1 + 2 + 3}} \\
    \end{array}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will give you:

[image]